# unable to set data to Cloud Firestore from web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to set some data from a text input from a web page to cloud firestore. I have this in one html file with the below code in a  tag.

I used the code based on Firestore docs.

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js";
       
const firebaseConfig = {...};
      
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore();

   var name = getInputVal('cbname');

   function clubname() {
        
   db.collection("latest").add({
        clubName: name,
        })
    .then((docRef) => {
         console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
    .catch((error) => {
         console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    }
```

im using this code to get the input.

```
<label for="cbname">Club Name</label>
<input type="text" id="cbname" name="clubname">

<button class="save-button" onclick="clubname()" type="submit">Save</button>
```

ive tried a few different ways and I have ben unable to set data to a new document, add data to an existing document or update a document.

But for now, im just looking to set data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are importing `getFirestore` from wrong version of Firebase API, try this:

```
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-firestore.js";
```

Comment: oops didn't spot that. changing that still didn't save it :(

Comment: You have a strange mix of version 8 and version 9 code.  If you want to use API version 9, you should import the following functions:

`import { getFirestore, addDoc, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-firestore.js";`

And add the document like this:

`addDoc(collection(db, 'latest'), { clubName: name })`

Comment: this still didn't work, I tried changing the input to something fixed just to see if it was the save function. But still no luck.

Comment: Check your console logs for errors. I was able to add a document into a Firestore collection using your code with minor modifications.

Comment: I've checked that, and made a few minor changes nothing seemed to work, off the top of your head would you know any important areas I should try really go over top make it work